# json save to db and use it after

Tags: javascript

how to convert this json to database:

```
var obj = {
   'one' : ['qq','rr'],
   'pizda' : { }
}
```

and then retrive it and use it?

Comment: What platform are you using? What language?

Comment: He's using javascript, but what database?

Comment: @Maz: Oded rather meant: "What server side language?".

Answer (score 2):

You could store it in [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Overview+-+The+MongoDB+Interactive+Shell) without too much effort.

```
db.foo.save(obj); // Save obj to a database
db.foo.find(); // find it again.
```

You might want to give a bit more details.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the database runs on the webserver and you thus need to pass the JSON as a string around between webserver and webbrowser, then the answer depends on the server side language you're using.

If you're using PHP, then you can convert between a JSON string and a PHP array using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

If you're using JSP/Java, then there are several libraries available to convert between a JSON string and a Java object, the popular ones being [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/java/) and [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org).

If you're using ASP/.NET, then there are several libraries available as well, under each [Google JSONSharp](http://code.google.com/p/jsonsharp/).

Also see the bottom of [this page](http://www.json.org/) for an overview of several JSON parsers/formatters in various languages.